# Is a php accelerator/php cache a must?

Tags: php, vbulletin

I run a linode VPS with 512MB of memory and I was wondering if a PHP accelerator or PHp cache is a must have?

The point of the server is a vBulletin forum.

Which one would you recommend if so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

protip: 99% of systems administration is trial & error

no one can tell you what the memory-footprint/performance tradeoff for your version of vbulletin running your inevitable customizations at your traffic levels, sharing a tiny vps with whatever else you're doing, is going to be.

that said, apc is pretty much standard-issue at this point.  I'd have to have a reason *not* to set it up on any new php environment, and you haven't shown one yet.

edit: and if this is apache/mod_php you'd better have your maxclients/serverlimit down at like 10

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I actually have it at 24 right now but I do notice apache gobbling up memory sometimes. Do you say 10 because of the memory? If I upgrade to 728 what would you bump it to from your experience?

I understand it's trial and error and I'm learning a lot but advice is always a helpful guide.

Comment: mpm_prefork_module: 

    StartServers          1
    MinSpareServers       3
    MaxSpareServers       6
    ServerLimit          24
    MaxClients           24
    MaxRequestsPerChild   3000

Comment: Is the default configuration sufficient for APC?

Comment: Yes, always leave things at the default until you can prove a difference is worth it with a test.  In your case I'd focus on gathering facts first, make decisions later.  Something like Munin will give you nice charts and is very quick and easy to setup.

Comment: Thanks.

I did some research and I hear to choose collectd over munin. What would you say to that?

Comment: see the first line

Comment: Is it bad that apc is showing 100% fragmentation?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to try this is doing some tests and testing the performance.

I used Accelerators sometime ago when I deployed SquirrelMail to 100k users, the performance increased 5 times. After that I got other problems and solved using a reverse proxy in the front and distributing the load through more machines.

But it's a great solution and the unique thing you can do is test.